# Can a polynomial be expressed as a rational function in Weierstrass functions?

Tags: polynomials, special-functions, elliptic-functions

In the theory of elliptic functions we have the well-known Weierstrass $\zeta$-function (which is, by the way, not elliptic but satisfies identities
$$
\zeta(z+2\omega_i)=\zeta(z)+2\zeta(\omega_i),
$$
where $2\omega_1, 2\omega_2$ are periods of its derivative $\zeta'(z)$).

My question is: is it possible to construct a non-constant polynomial in $z$ as a ratio of polynomials in expressions of the type $\zeta(kz+\delta)$ (where $k$ is a non-zero integer and $\delta$ is an arbitrary complex number) and its derivatives in $z$?

Motivation comes from the problem of discretization of commuting differential operators but it is probably irrelevant here.

Comment: A polynomial has a finite number of zeros, but the Weierstrass functions have poles in period parallelograms.

Comment: @Somos the problem is that the Weierstrass zeta-function is not elliptic so the ratio of such function is (typically) not elliptic so it is possible  that such a function has no poles but is non-trivial

Comment: For some reason, I am reminded of the [Zolotarev polynomials](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Zolotarev_polynomials), which are polynomials that are compactly expressed in terms of theta functions and Jacobi elliptic functions.